# To install ROS .debs by specifying their versions?

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title says, I'd like to know if there's any way in ROS to install by specifying `.deb` version.

`apt-get` allows to install specific version of `.deb`; by following [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version) I can do like:

```
$ apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-comm=1.9.50-0precise-20131007-1614-+0000
```

But apparently the error occurs when I specify an older version (this version should be valid since I checked from [here](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/lists/backfill-shadow-fixed_precise_main_amd64_Packages)):

```
$ apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-comm=1.9.48-0precise-20130824-0432-+0000
E: Version '1.9.48-0precise-20130824-0432-+0000' for 'ros-hydro-ros-comm' was not found
```

I assume this error happens because the `.deb` repo I use ([shadow-fixed](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdeb/DevelopersGuide#How_pbuilder_works)) does not keep the older versions. I refrain from trying to hack too much into ROS' `.deb` repository to find a URL that could provide older .debs to `apt-get`. I'd rather ask for official ways to achieve this if any.

If there's `.deb` archive available that would be easy solution, but I don't stick to it. Thanks!

---

**Background of this question**; we've been talking to some corporate users and found that they tend to "freeze" the fundamental software (that we've been maintaining) once they have built it from source for a stability reason, often very long time ago so that the software can be obsolete compared to its recent versions. Now that we've been shifting to provide the same software from .deb, which is by itself very convenient and appreciated, the new issue here is `apt-get` with certain `upgrade` option replaces with the latest version.

So back to the original question, if there's a way to specify the older version numbers to install, that would be extremely useful for users who want to focus on their development.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89211/to-install-ros-.debs-by-specifying-their-versions?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't specify the older versions from packages.ros.org, they get removed when newer versions are added to the repository. If you want to lock to a specific version, you will probably have to create and host your own mirror of the debian repository, using a tool such as debmirror.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-10-12**:
Helpful to know debmirror. Now I've escalated to wonder how to take a snapshot of all (or as available as possible) depended packages. Maybe better to be asked somewhere beyond ROS community?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-12-12**:
`apt-mirror` as described in this updated wiki page works pretty good for me http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors#Creating_a_packages.ros.org_mirror to obtain all built `.debs` at the moment.